# spring-cloud-dataflow-kubernetes app memory limit

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have set deployment properties with `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.limits.memory=300Mi`. But after the stream was deployed, I check the memory limit with `docker stats`, It still returned `xxx/640Mi`.

I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/blob/v1.1.1.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/kubernetes/AbstractKubernetesDeployer.java#L191), and found that the code may print some debug log. But even if I set `LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_SPI_KUBERNETES=DEBUG`
, the debug log still wouldn't show up.

I have no idea what's going wrong here.

Comment: Hi, Can you also show how you passed the deployment properties when you deploy the stream?

Comment: I passed the deployment properties with spring cloud data flow shell `stream deploy --name xxx --properties "spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.limits.memory=300Mi"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with set deployment properties with "app.xxx.spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.limits.memory=300Mi", and it finally succeeded. It's likely that I got wrong with the way passing deployment properties.